# How to use fabric js html5 canvas library custom build in Next.js

Tags: next.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I needed to use the eraser feature of fabric in my Next.js project (version 12.3.1). However fabric does not give the eraser feature in its default build (the build which we get from its CDN link or via npm). Hence I downloaded the dev build (`fabric.js`) and minified build (`fabric.min.js`) of fabric with the eraser feature. Now I am not able to integrate this custom build with the eraser into my project.

At first I tried to replace the files in the `node_modules/fabric/dist` directory with the files I downloaded for the custom build (`fabric.js` and `fabric.min.js`) and then I re-served the project. It did not work since whenever I tried to use  `new fabric.EraserBrush(canvas)` it threw up an error stating fabric.EraserBrush is not a constructor, which means that the custom build was not integrated into my project.

I also tried running inside the `fabric` directory
`node build.js modules=ALL requirejs exclude=gestures,accessors`
But it threw up this error

```
Built distribution to dist/fabric.js (requirejs-compatible) Minification failed using uglifyjs with uglifyjs  --compress --mangle --output fabric.min.js fabric.js Minifier error output: Error: Command failed: uglifyjs  --compress --mangle --output fabric.min.js fabric.js 'uglifyjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Any help would be much appreciated!